# change background color of table row clicked

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to highlight the row of the last item clicked. Tried some jquery code found in searches and none of it even tries to work. Must be doing something basic wrong. Here's a jsfiddle with one solution tried: http://jsfiddle.net/birchy/he9ts/1/

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>====></td>
<td class='msgRow' onclick='loadMsg();'>Content1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>====></td>
<td class='msgRow' onclick='loadMsg();'>Content2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>====></td>
<td class='msgRow' onclick='loadMsg();'>Content3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>====></td>
<td class='msgRow' onclick='loadMsg();'>Content4</td>
</tr>
</table>

function loadMsg()
{
alert('row clicked');
$(this).closest("tr").css('background-color','green');
$(this).css('background-color','red');  
}
```

Comment: Since you are using jQuery already, you should not use `onclick` attribute, but bind the event handler to the elements via jQuery in the first place.

Comment: Check in the console that "this" is not referred to what you've clicked on. It referred to the window. I suggest you using Firebug and check things like that in the future.

Comment: I've never been able to figure out how the firebug console works, nor have I found any useful tutorials online. When I open firebug and click on "console" then click on the table row, all I get in the list is the info on the POST associated with the ajax call that is made in the js function as the bg color changing logic. If I look at the option in the "Console" drop down menu, it only talks about showing js errors and warnings. I don't know how I could view that the this object is.

Comment: I can see the DOM in firebug, but don't see and "this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

First, pass the element clicked on your function by using `this` only

```
<tr>
    <td>===></td>
    <td class="msgRow" onclick="onclick(this)">Content 3</td>
</tr>
```

Then on your js

```
function loadMsg(e){
    // remove first the background applied on all tr
    $('.msgRow').closest('tr').css('background-color','none'); 

    // remove also the background applied on all 'msgRow' classes
    $('.msgRow').css('background-color','none');

    // then you can now change the background color of the clicked row and cell
    $(e).closest('tr').css('background-color','green');
    $(e).css('background-color','red');
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rKxV2/1/)**

Comment: for some reason, while the code works perfectly in jsfiddle, only the highlight code works on my live page, the code that clears previously highlighted rows doesn't, they remain highlighted. And I can't find any significant difference other than I don't highlight both the td and the tr, just the tr.
    `$('.msgRow').css('background-color','none');`
    `$('.msgRow').closest('tr').css('background-color','none');`
    `$(e).closest("tr").css('background-color','#CCD9DC');`

Comment: I may leave it that way, as a way to show all clicked rows, but I'd sure like to figure out why they won't clear.

Comment: timed out on editing the first comment, so here's a better version of the code:



`<tr class="msgRow" onclick='loadMsg($MID,this);'>`

`function loadMsg(m,e)`
`{`
`$('.msgRow').css('background-color','none');`
`$('.msgRow').closest('tr').css('background-color','none');`
`$(e).closest("tr").css('background-color','#CCD9DC');`
`}`

Comment: yeah! it is better but i think you don't need the `closest` method.

Comment: Found out why highlight wasn't clearing. In live example, the table sits in a div with a bg color. When I change "none" to the actual color of the bg, it works fine.

`<tr class="msgRow" onclick='loadMsg($MID,this);'> `

`function loadMsg(m,e) { `
`$('.msgRow').css('background-color','#DDEAED'); ``$(e).closest("tr").css('background-color','#CCD9DC'); `
`}`

Answer (score 2):

Only you need is pass this on the onclick on each `td` to get wich td has been clicked:

```
<tr>
    <td>====></td>
    <td class='msgRow' onclick='loadMsg(this);'>Content3</td>
</tr>
```

And you Js will be:

```
function loadMsg(e)
{
    alert(e);
    $(e).closest("tr").css('background-color','green');
    $(e).css('background-color','red'); 
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rKxV2/)

Another way only Jquery (Recomended):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.msgRow').on('click', function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").css('background-color','green');
        $(this).css('background-color','red');  
    });
});
```

and removing the onclik in all `td`.